# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, parsing, json.net, webclient

I'm trying to use Steam's Web API to receive JSON and parse it using JSON.Net. I'm simply hard-coding a URL where I know I'll receive JSON. I'm running into the following error when I run it though:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

The error points to line 22 of my controller:

> Line 22:             SteamResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

Here are my classes:

```
public class Game
{
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public int playtime_forever { get; set; }
    public int? playtime_2weeks { get; set; }
}

public class SteamResponse
{
    public int game_count { get; set; }
    public List<Game> games { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public SteamResponse response { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
        List<Game> gameList = new List<Game>();

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        var json = wc.DownloadString("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=" + steamAPIKey + "&steamid=76561197994394917&format=json");

        SteamResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SteamResponse>(json);
```

I've visited the URL in browser to verify it's correct, and I've also tested the URL using JSON Lint. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - I've checked other topics and checked for the problems they've listed but didn't find them.

[Here is a link to the JSON I'm attempting to receive](http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=30A260C0B3B379A218C5533CC14CA96D&steamid=76561197994394917&format=json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a `RootObject` type, but you're not using it in the deserialization. Have you tried:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
// access root.response;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I've tried RootObject and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Perhaps it's an invalid stream API key, the JSON link you provided is working for me - https://dotnetfiddle.net/2KP7HO

Comment: Well the API key is in the URL for the JSON link, so it must be correct right? I even copied your code example into a local console app I just created and ran it - but got the same error.  I'm confused.

Comment: Have you debugged that you're getting back the same JSON response?

Comment: Okay so the problem was apparently my connection. For some reason webclient wouldn't pull in JSON on my mobile connection - I switched to a different connection and it was fine. It's working now. It was also important that I was using the wrong object - RootObject - to parse to, so thanks for pointing that out.