# JSON Deserialization in C# error

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON in C#, but when I run my program I'm getting this error message:

[image]

I've looked through all my code, and I can't find a "<" anywhere there shouldn't be one, and I went to the web address that the json is coming from:
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.1211&lon=-88.5694&FcstType=json,
and there isn't a "<" character. I used json2csharp.com to translate to C# classes, and everything there seems fine as well. Any thoughts? Here is the part of my code where I try to do all of this:

```
var http = new HttpClient();
var url = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.1211&lon=-88.5694&FcstType=json";
var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject2));
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
var data = (RootObject2)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
return data;
```

Comment: Rather than visiting the web address you're getting it from, why don't you look in the debugger at what you've actually received? Maybe there's something on the server which is giving you different results when you fetch from C# than when you visit it in a browser. Ideally, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can we see just the part where you read the json into a string(s) and the line for the deserialization call?

Comment: I'd say there is a reasonable chance you're getting xml from http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.1211&lon=-88.5694&FcstType=xml rather than json from http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.1211&lon=-88.5694&FcstType=json but Jon is (of course!) absolutely right - better to debug what you are actually trying to serialise than to speculate

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I look in the debugger to see what I'm actually getting? Sorry, I'm super new to this.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell *exactly* given that you haven't shown any code, but generally speaking you'd set a breakpoint at a place after you've received the data but before you've tried to parse it as JSON. Then look at the variables in the locals/watch windows.

Comment: Generally if you are getting a "<" back, you are actually getting an error back. Then your deserializer is trying to deserialize the html page; which results in the error that you are receiving.

Comment: Use newtonsoft.json package  for deserialize json  might be it will give you proper data seems like something going wrong memory stream or encoding in bytes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is failing because you are not setting a header the API is expecting.  Add a user agent and check for success prior to attempting to read the response.

```
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.1211&lon=-88.5694&FcstType=json";
       //Supply the same header as chrome
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject2));
            var data = (RootObject2)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check that answer, it says some issue with the connection, that he was not receiving the full response from the API

[Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849382/json-net-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value)

Comment: Possible, but I think it's unlikely that the connection is bad because I'm receiving data fine from three other APIs (from different sites).

Comment: i added this two line before the call and it can see IsSuccessStatusCode true  http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));